# $scope.var giving undefined in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ng-pattern

I am using angularjs to do client side validation on a textbox where I need input as alphanumeric chars only. If the textbox is left empty or non-alphanumeric char is entered, the submitform sends 'false' to JS which is desired but the problem is it doesn't pass the non-alphnumeric char itself (in the scope).

**JSP file:**

```
    <form name="addressForm" method="post" 
ng-submit="submitform(addressForm.$valid)" novalidate>
    ..
    <input ng-model="address" type="text" 
**ng-pattern**="/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$/" required="true"/>
```

**JS file:**

```
$scope.submitform= function(isValid){
var inputAddr = $scope.address;
alert(inputAddr);  //coming as undefined
...
```

Now when I input an alphanumeric character in input box 'address' in jsp it gives me **undefined** on alerting it in JS (probably because of pattern which filters the char being non-alphanumeric). If I remove ng-pattern, it passes the submitForm passes 'true' as if every input is "as expected". The reason I want to access $scope.address is to check and value and display different error message for "empty" and a "non-alphanumeric" validation.

Any help is appreciated !

Comment: Unfortunately that is how `ng-pattern` works, it will simply leave the model as undefined as long as the value does not match. We had to stop using it because we ran into the exact same problem. Our solution was to do the validation in the controller, but I don't think it's a *good* solution. Angular's form-validation mechanics is in my opinion broken to the point where it's more or less completely useless.

Comment: Sorry, I don't agree with you. Angular form's validation is very usefull, but we need to understand how it works. The model value is assigned just when the model is valid. When it is not valid, we must to check $viewValue property to get what the user typed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the model is not valid, the value is not assigned to the model. If you want to see what the user has typed, you need to check $viewValue:

You must to add name attribute to input, so change your input html to:

```
<input ng-model="address" type="text" name="address"
ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$/" required="true"/>
```

And change your submit function to

```
$scope.submitform = function(isValid) {
    console.log($scope.addressForm.address.$viewValue);  
}
```

Comment: Yes this is another approach. Good catch on needing to supply a value for the `name` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just need to know what the validation error is.

You can check the `$error` property the `FormController` (`addressForm` in your case) to see what validations passed or failed.

For example, if the input is empty, then the "required" validation will have failed and `addressForm.$error.required` will be an `Array` containing the inputs that failed this validation.

If the "required" validation succeeded, then `addressForm.$error.required` will just be `false`.

You can use this in angular expressions quite easily:

```
<p ng-show="addressForm.$error.required">This field is required.</p>
```

Or you can access the form through the `$scope` object that is associated with the view:

```
if ($scope.addressForm.$error.required) {
   // required validation failed
}
```

Check out the documentation for [FormController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController) and [ngModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController).

Comment: When doing that you have to make sure your `form` does not suddenly end up inside a directive that creates an isolated `scope` (like `ng-if`) or you will suddenly no longer be able to access the `FormController` any more. As long as you know that will never happen it will work.

Comment: @ivami Yeah, definitely it's quite a pain with any sort of dynamic forms. I mostly agree with your comment, validation in Angular should be easier :)

Comment: PS: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19140386/angular-access-formcontroller-in-controller) might help for people struggling w/locating FormController's in dynamically generated forms.

Comment: Yeah, there are definitely ways to locate the `FormController` reference, but I honestly think it's better to just roll your own validation with a combination of custom directives and services invoked from the controller. But we shouldn't have to jump through hoops to access the input-fields. I hope they look at that for Angular 2.0.

Comment: I like your `formLocator` idea, I might even look at using it, I just think it shouldn't be needed :)

Comment: @SunilD. It's true that .required will let me know whether the field is empty or filled but how would I know if the filled in value is alpha numeric or not unless I make use of $viewValue.

Comment: @user3137592 ng-pattern is also a "validator" so when the pattern does not match your alpha numeric regex, it will also set a value on the $error object. Check the value of $error.pattern.