# Angular Form Validation: What is the right syntax for $valid, if form name comes from model?

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation

First of all, here is the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/AAWNfna43rHtpjZ7PG4L?p=preview

There are 2 forms, the form-name of the first one comes from the model and the form name of the second one is written directly in the view.

[image]

First one does not work:

```
{{ formName.$valid }}
```

the second one works:

```
{{ myForm2.$valid}}
```

How is the right syntax for forms with dynamically names?

These are the both forms:

```
  <div class="formBox">
    <ng-form name="{{formName}}">
      <input name="{{inputName}}" ng-model="myInput1" required> Required Input Field
    </ng-form>
    <span class="el">Form-Valid: {{ formName.$valid }}</span>
    <span class="el">Input-Valid: {{ formName.inputName.$valid }}</span>
  </div>


  <div class="formBox">
    <ng-form name="myForm2">
      <input name="myInput2" ng-model="myInput2" required> Required Input Field
    </ng-form>
    <span class="el">Forum-Valid: <strong>{{ myForm2.$valid}}</strong></span>
    <span class="el">Input-Valid: <strong>{{ myForm2.myInput2.$valid}}</strong></span>
  </div>
```

Comment: so now I can see what you were trying to accomplish from the last question.  unfortunately this isn't something that angular supports currently, without some sort of workaround, due to how the `$interpolate` provider works.  There are multiple issues in the bug tracker related to this.

Comment: basically, by the time that the expression `{{formName}}` is evaluated, the validation has already been wired up.

Comment: here is one such possibility of a workaround to find the form itself: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22487840/2495283

Comment: thank you, it is an approach..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever a form is instantiated, it creates and instance of `FormController` which is published to `$scope` using the `name` attribute.  However, because you are using dynamic names, this causes you to have a primitive on `$scope` already, which cannot be replaced by the `FormController` object.

One way to resolve this is to use an `ng-init` to isolate the `FormController` object using the bracket syntax (in this case, `this` is a reference to `$scope`), and assign this form to a unique name.  Note the use of the bracket syntax for the input field property as well.

```js
$scope.setForm = function(form) {
  $scope.theForm = form;
  console.log($scope.theForm);
};
```

```html
<ng-form name="{{formName}}">
  <div ng-init="setForm(this[formName])"></div>
  <input name="{{inputName}}" ng-model="myInput1" required>Required Input Field
</ng-form>
<span class="el">Form-Valid: {{ theForm.$valid }}</span>
<span class="el">Input-Valid: {{ theForm[inputName].$valid }}</span>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/BRf2Fz00rYLszFzb8kjo?p=preview

Knowing `this`, you could also reference the object directly using the bracket syntax with `$scope`:

```html
<ng-form name="{{formName}}">
  <input name="{{inputName}}" ng-model="myInput1" required>Required Input Field
</ng-form>
<span class="el">Form-Valid: {{ this[formName].$valid }}</span>
<span class="el">Input-Valid: {{ this[formName][inputName].$valid }}</span>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/MB8SkVbWw0cl7GqWcbpC?p=preview

Comment: that's an elegant solution! Thank you!

Comment: Second question would be: How can I change the styles live on validity?

Comment: you should have no problem using either `ng-style` or `ng-class` with these expressions.

Comment: would you see my next question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34044582/ thank you!

Comment: I read through it briefly, but I'm on a mobile device for the rest of the day, and may not be able to examine the code in depth, unfortunately.

Comment: this approach has unfortunately no effect within ng-class: http://plnkr.co/edit/i7aeoFSE6uvcbUxkNVpC?p=preview

Comment: @Vienna actually it does work, but you have a flaw.  The expression syntax (`{{ }}`) is used when you have JavaScript variables that you want to treat as text output.  In case of `ng-class`, however, you are in a JavaScript statement, and you want the variables as they are.  therefore, you don't need the brackets. http://plnkr.co/edit/LaycziXoWBqkryu8SLXn?p=preview